# how to translate or remove the "Chapter" and "Table Of Content" strings that asciidoctor-pdf insert in the genrated pdf

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor-pdf

A asciidoc document writen in french,
but asciidoctor-pdf precedes chapters with an english "Chapter" String
and the tabl of content with an english "Table Of Content" title.
How to repalce/translate/avoid that english strings in the final pdf ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate [localization attributes](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/document-attributes-reference/#builtin-attributes-i18n).

Comment: Thanks, I had tried `chapter-label` with no success, the solution was to use `chapter-signifier`